# NFS doesn't sync files if characters are modified in a file

Tags: php, synchronization, nfs

I'm having a strange problem with my vagrant setup: changing characters in a file and saving it doesn't reflect the change in the vm. But if I add/remove some characters or add in a few blank links, everything works fine.

I have already checked if I have **opcache** enabled on my PHP5.5 and "*php -i | grep opcache*" get any result ... so I imagine it's no.

Already tested too another vagrant (1.7.2) version, same result.

My configuration is :

- Windows 7 Pro
- Vagrant 1.6.3 with plugin [WinNFSd](https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd)
- VirtualBox 4.3.12
- Centos6.5 Box
- PHP 5.5.19
- Apache 2.4.10
- PhpStorm 8 (but problem is same with SublimeText 3 and Notepad++)

Here is a video of a test from me for show you the problem :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k70fiwfw6mopjs7/2015-03-24%2020-47-07.mp4?dl=0

Two weeks I work on this problem, it will make me crazy ...
I already tried Rsync and Samba or default vagrant synch folder but it doesn't meet my needs.

I really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: I'm having the same problem but on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on sublime was `atomic_save` setting being true. Not sure if there is an equivalent setting for PHPStorm/Notepad++

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3888